# Identifying AWS unhealthy hosts in target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have multiple targetGroups running behind an AWS ALB. Moreover, I set cloudwatch alarms to monitor the health of those target groups. Whenever, a target in this group generates an unhealthyhost alarm, AWS sends an email alerting me that a target in this group suffered from being unhealthy. However, the alarm, and the email does not notify me which instance from this target group is unhealthy.

Is there a way or a solution to implement and find out which target in this group is the one who caused the issue?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/LogASGroupState.html. You can register a lambda function to listen to change events and capture the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Trigger the lambda function when an EC2 instance is terminated
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "instance_terminated" {
  name = "ChefCleanup-InstanceTerminated-rule"
  description = "Capture each EC2 instance termination"
  event_pattern = <<PATTERN
  {
    "source": [ "aws.ec2" ],
    "detail-type": [ "EC2 Instance State-change Notification" ],
    "detail": {
      "state": [ "terminated" ]
    }
  }
PATTERN
}

# Set event target to call the lambda
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "instance_terminated" {
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.instance_terminated.name}"
  target_id = "chef-cleanup-lambda"
  arn      = "${aws_lambda_function.chef_cleanup.arn}"
}
```